# Why isn't it hiding the NA value (R)

Tags: r, na

Clearly removed NA values but they're still being shown:

[image: code example]

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post the code as text in your question.

Answer (score -2):

Here, the 'x' still have NA values and any operation on an NA will return `NA`.  According to `?NA`

> Numerical computations using NA will normally result in NA: a possible exception is where NaN is also involved, in which case either might result (which may depend on the R platform). Logical computations treat NA as a missing TRUE/FALSE value, and so may return TRUE or FALSE if the expression does not depend on the NA operand.

```
x <- c(NA, 5, 10)
rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)
x -rng[1]
[1] NA  0  5
```